# How to prove sample variance has a gamma distribution by using mgf.

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

If $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n \sim  \mathcal N (\mu, \sigma^2) $ i.i.d. and $S^2$ is the sample variance. How do I go about calculating the moment generating function of $S^2 $ itself and deduce that $S^2$ has a gamma distribution?

Comment: Use the definition of $S^2$ in the definition of it's moment generating function, then just use independence.

Comment: see my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2627627/151735